# What is the origin of the phrase "bo selecta"?

Tags: etymology, music

The phrase means literally "good song" or "good DJ". *selecta* is the DJ ("the selector"). But why that spelling? And where does *bo* come from? Is it from the French *beau* or the Latin *bona*? Is there a link via Jamaican English? What evidence of use exists prior to [the 1999 song](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re-Rewind_%28The_Crowd_Say_Bo_Selecta%29)?

Comment: Do you mean that it does not come from this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bo'_Selecta! and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyUNqnE84Ks

Comment: And the TV show's name comes [from a song title](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re-Rewind_(The_Crowd_Say_Bo_Selecta)).

Answer (score 6):

One explanation is *bo* is a gunshot, representing appreciation. And *selecta* is the DJ, the one who selects the music. So when the crowd say "Bo selecta!" they're giving appreciation and want the song played again.

From the [Drum n Bass Dictionary](http://www.djklusta.co.uk/index.php?id=62):

> **Bo!** - Simulated gunshot.. when a tune is big, say this loud if you want a rewind. In Jamaica people used to fire blanks all the time when a tune was big.
>
> **Booyaka!** - an expression, like a gunshot.. say it loud when you want the rewind.
>
> **Boomshot** - see booyaka, bo
>
> **Selector** - A DJ, the person who is mixing records,

The phrase "bo selecta" was featured in the 1999 song "Re-Rewind (The Crowd Say Bo Selecta)" by The Artful Dodger featuring Craig David.
In the song 'Gunman' by '187 Lockdown', the phrase "bo selecta" can also be heard.

Comment: Do the crowd say _Bo Selecta_ or is it a request to the DJ to replay the tune when the crowd say "Bo" as in _Selecta, when the crowd say "Bo", please play that tune again_.